# How to move Ion-Slides next after every 10 second in Ionic 4?

Tags: html, typescript, angular6, ionic4

I'm creating Ionic 4 plus Angular app. In that I'm using Ion-Slides to show number of questions one by one. Now I want move Ion-Slides next after every 10 seconds.

[Ionic Slides Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the ionic 4 explanation

html.

```
   <ion-slides  [options]="slideOpts"  > 
          <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of cars">
            <img src="{{item}}" width="400px" height="250px">
          </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {IonSlides} from '@ionic/angular';
export class HomePage {
     @ViewChild(IonSlides) slides: IonSlides;

cars=[
"https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52648.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Right-Front-Three-Quarter-52645.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Right-Side-52646.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Left-Front-Three-Quarter-52647.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52649.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Rear-view-52650.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80"

];




ngOnInit(){
  this.slides.startAutoplay().then(()=>{})}
}
 slideOpts = {
   speed: 10000
  };
```

You can grab the component with ViewChild then you can use its methods on page initialisation. `startAutoplay()` is mentioned in the docs you linked. Slide options allows you to set the speed of transitions. If you want a true solution that flips the slide every 10 seconds you could write an async method which changes the slide every 10 seconds. Comment if you need help.

Comment: Hi , Basically I have place questions on each slides, and used countdown timer for 10 seconds for every slides change.

Comment: But one slide move to next after 10 seconds, the (angular 6 countdown) countdown timer not restart.i have facing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this,

.html

```
<ion-slides  #slid autoplay="5000" loop="true" speed="500" pager="true"  > 
          <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of cars">
            <img src="{{item}}" width="400px" height="250px">
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slides>
```

.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';




@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;


cars=[
"https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52648.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Right-Front-Three-Quarter-52645.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Right-Side-52646.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Left-Front-Three-Quarter-52647.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Front-view-52649.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80",
  "https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/1056x594/ec/79/85/9802/img/ol/Lamborghini-Aventador-Rear-view-52650.jpg?v=201711021421&q=80"

];


}
```

here is the stackblitz link [https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-8qkwca ]

Comment: Hello Sir, Given Stackblitz link is not open .

Comment: is this not an ionic 3 explanation ?

Comment: This is also work fine, But i need ionic 4.Thank You.